# Ionic 3 - How to move the theme>variable.scss File

Tags: angular, webpack, ionic3

This seems like an easy question, but I can't find the answer.

I have an Ionic 3 project created with ionic CLI so Angular/Webpack.  I am trying to delete the theme folder and move the variable.scss file to my sharded scss folder.  When I do it - everything blows up and I get an IDE error of "Sass Error
File to import not found or unreadable: /Users/blah/src/theme/variables.scss. Parent style sheet: stdin"

Comment: Is there a setting in `node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/`?  I haven't done this before.

Comment: @PhilipBrack Not sure, but I wouldn't want to do that incase someone updates that module.

Comment: So what I do is I hook into npm "post-install" and copy my changes.  believe it or not I am 99% sure this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you move the variables.scss, you have to change the path. Ionic CLI put the path under "variableSassFiles" (in @ionic\app-scripts\config/sass.config.js).

So you have to customize the sass.config.js and put it in your own folder. Afterwards update the package.json and add:

```
  "config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./your-path-to-config-folder/sass.config.js"
  },
```

For more Information see https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration

Comment: In my app I make these changes via npm so I can upgrade.  Hook- `"postinstall": "node ./post-install.js"`  where post-install does several things including updating referenced file.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the answer.  Grr.. I wish I could just have "config": {
    "variableSassFiles": ["src/shared/scss/variables.scss"]
  }, in the package.json.